# pnacl-ld: Invalid archive member header magic string

Tags: c++, static-linking, google-nativeclient

While creating a pexe from the libraries I am getting below error:

pnacl-ld: .a: Invalid archive member header magic string 
/30             1370435922  1000  1000  100664  103140    `

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lib file was having file other than .o file. The was having cpp file (renamed to .orig by git)

This was creating a problem. I came to know when I did

$less < libname >

Which gave me list of files in .a

Comment: If you found a solution to your original problem, you can indicate it by marking your own answer accepted. This is common practice on SO and it helps other people who run into the same problem.

Comment: from where can I access the less command..!?.. I am trying to build the source from windows environment.